# Replace one character with another character 2 spaces over

Tags: regex, sed

Here is a piece of the xml data I am parsing

`<marc:subfield code="¿">aDLC</marc:subfield>`

I need to take the "¿" and replace it with the lowercase "a"
The resulting data should look like this:

`<marc:subfield code="a">DLC</marc:subfield>`

The sed regex I am running is:

`s/"¿">([a-z])/"\1">/g`

Comment: Brilliant. And exactly *where* did you get stuck???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape `(` and `)` to be used them as capturing group `(...)` in sed's default `BRE` flavor:

```
s='<marc:subfield code="¿">aDLC</marc:subfield>'
sed 's/"¿">\([a-z]\)/"\1">/g' <<< "$s"

<marc:subfield code="a">DLC</marc:subfield>
```

Or use extended regex using `-E` and avoid escaping them:

```
sed -E 's/"¿">([a-z])/"\1">/g' <<< "$s"
```